# BBedit regular expression find string

Tags: regex, bbedit

How I can find with bbedit regular expression all the lines containing the word text+""

```
Text("ciao") <- this is the type off line that i want to search
"Hello"
how are you = "test"
```

I tried with this regular expression `("[a-zA-Z 0-9]+)`, but I found all the lines that have `"`

Comment: Try `\w+\("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"\)`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. Are you looking for a specific word (aka "Text"), or what looks like a function call? That is the syntax `functionName("parameter")`? If it's function calls, should it also match `functionName ( "parameter" )`? What could be inside the parameter? Can it have escaped quotes? (that is `functionName("She said \"ok\" and left")`).